# Redmine very slow for every pages

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, redmine

We are using redmine on Debian 7 and we are facing very slow response time when navigating on it.

Hardware configuration :

- RAM : 8Go
- Proc : 4 Proc, 2800 MHz, cache size : 2048KB

Software configuration :

**MySQL**

- version : 5.5.43
- innodb_buffer_pool_size : 4Go
- No slow queries detected (seconds thresholds set to 3)

**Ruby**

- Version : 1.9.3p547

**Passenger**

- Version : 5.0.6
- Passenger is taking a log of CPU when navigating on Redmine

Performance analysis I did and results :

**MySQL Tunner**

- nothing to do after running the script

**Munin**

- MySQL threads avg : 3.2

We recently have migrated redmine from a server which was running under Centos 5.5, with the same ROR environment, the same load,  the performance was a way better than on Debian 7.

Do you have any suggestion / directions I could investigate more deeply ?

Thank you for your help.

Cheers